# Is Delphi 2010 ready for production use?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am currently using Delphi 2006 a few days ago I downloaded a copy of Delphi 2010.

How stable is Delphi 2010?

Should I wait until the first service pack comes out before moving to this version?

**EDIT**

I have been using Delphi 2010 for a few months and it is great.

The version of **Rave reports (7.7BE)** that comes with Delphi 2010 **is full of bugs** and has made migrating software from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 2010 a **nightmare**.
Rave Reports 8.0BE has just as many bugs

Comment: this sounds like a good question for forums.codegear.com/embarcadero.public.delphi.non-technical, not here.

Comment: Every question on Stack Overflow could be well placed elsewhere. However, the POINT of SO is to be a central place for all programming knowledge, and as such, this question fits right in. If you actually think the question is inappropriate, flag it for close rather than preach in the comments.

Comment: @Tim: my point was that SO is not a discussion forum - sorry I was not more explicit.  Your comment about flagging is valid, even if a bit preachy.  ;-)

Comment: If you're programming commercially, ReportBuilder from digital-metaphors will pay for itself in one day's use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems to be more stable than D2009.

But in regards to your question, who can tell?

D2010 was released *days* ago. It will take at least a couple months to be confident that all major issues have been uncovered by Delphi users. Then you can judge whether any are show-stoppers for you. If your release timeline can't hold off that long, then plan on using both compilers for a little bit. The good news for you is that it's quite easy to write code which works in both.

Comment: Looking back, Delphi 2009, 2010, and XE have been on an upward trajectory in terms of how stable I have felt them to be.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, it's very stable and usable.  More so than even Delphi 2009, which I also like a lot.

I understand a lot of issues with Generics have been cleaned up, too.

Definitely ready for production use.

Answer (score 7):

I like Bruce's answer. Let me just add to what he said that debugger visualizers can make debugging a whole lot easier.  Between visualizers and improved generics it's definitely worth upgrading from 2009.  (The RTTI and Attributes can be helpful too, depending on your program.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Yes.

Comment: He also asked how stable, and should he wait for a service pack.

Comment: Okay, answers:  Very Stable.  No.

Comment: I am sorry, Nick, but since you work for Embarcadero, why should we believe you in this case? Even if Delphi 2010 were utter garbage you would be compelled to say otherwise.
Just to be sure: Delphi 2010 is, as far as I have used it, very stable. Waiting for a service pack is not necessary. The only reason I have not started to use it in production but rather stick with Delphi 2007 for now, is unicode.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Delphi 2010 is the best Delphi ever

Answer (score 0):

Using it for quite some time. More stable then 2009, 2007, 2005.
I even have days without a single crash. I hope it will be weeks for the next D2011.